# My code prints junk values, when i print the contents in buffer

Tags: c

This is a Program to take std input and display 72 characters ended with a newline character
if the number of input is less than 72 it has to appended with terminating null characters, If i print the buffer i get junk values. What is wrong here

```
int main()  {
int buffer[ MAX_CHAR ];
int count = 0, ch = 0, i = 0;

while( (ch = getchar() != '@') ) {
    // Buffer used to collect the i/p characters from the std i/p
    buffer[count++] = ch;
    if( MAX_CHAR - 1 == count ) {

        buffer[ MAX_CHAR + 1 ] = '\n';
        for(i = 0; i < MAX_CHAR; i++)
            printf("%c", buffer[i]);
        count  = 0;
        buffer[ MAX_CHAR ] = 0;
        }
    }
    //If the input character is less than 72, then append the rest with spaces
    if( count != MAX_CHAR - 1)  {

        for(i = count; i < MAX_CHAR - 1; i++)
            buffer[ count ] = ' ';
        buffer[ MAX_CHAR ] = '\n';
        for(i = 0; i < MAX_CHAR; i++)
            printf("%c", buffer[i]);
        }
   }
```

Comment: `int buffer[]` should be `char buffer[]` so you don't waste (assuming sizeof(int) == 4) 3 * MAX_CHAR bytes that you don't have to.

Comment: It sounds like the right time for you to learn about debuggers and start using one.

Comment: Note: The second loop will set one position (count) over and over, then write to MAX_CHAR (off the end of buffer) without ever setting the uninitialized values between count and MAX_CHAR which are being output.  (you probably meant: `buffer[ i ] = ' ';`)  P.S. - This is by no means null terminated, but would work as you're using at least (would display smiley and null char only though before spaces).

Answer (score 3):

You have:

```
while( (ch = getchar() != '@') ) {
```

This will be parsed as:

```
while( (ch = (getchar() != '@')) ) {
```

So `ch` will have the value 0 or 1. What you want is:

```
while( ((ch = getchar()) != '@') ) {
```

Additionally, you have undefined behavior in some places by writing past the end of the buffer:

```
int buffer[ MAX_CHAR ];
...
buffer[ MAX_CHAR + 1 ] = '\n';
...
buffer[ MAX_CHAR ] = 0;
```

Comment: That `=` vs `!=` precedence is exactly what I noticed first... Just couldn't remember for 100% sure which way it would go.